# SQL Server: LEFT OUTER JOIN with TOP 1 to Select at Most One Row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I basically need to do a left outer join on 2 tables (CarePlan and Referrals) problem is i need the newest Referral *If it exists*, its ok if it doesnt.

I have these 2 queries
1. joins the CarePlan/Referral tables - creates duplicate careplans if there are multiple referrals for a careplan, or has no referral information at all (left outer join)
2. select the top 1 Referral based on Date, given a CarePlanId

I'd like to combine these 2 so i grab all the careplans and its referrals if it exists, if it does - take only the newest referral

```
select * from CarePlan c //query 1
left outer join Referral r on 
r.CarePlanId = c.CarePlanId


select top 1 * from Referral r //query 2
where r.CarePlanId = '1'
order by ReferralDate desc
```

EDIT:

The first query gives me something like this:

```
CarePlanID    ReferralId     ReferralDate
----------    ----------     ------------
1             1              05/15/12
2             NULL           NULL
1             2              05/10/12  //Old date, dont want this careplan
```

The second query will give me the referral with the newest date

```
ReferralId    ReferralDate
----------    ------------
1             05/15/12
```

The Referral data, may have 0 or more referrals belonging to a Careplan

```
ReferralID  CarePlanId    Date
----------  ----------    ----
1           1             05/15/12
2           1             05/10/12
```

Ultimately I want a query that gives me careplans with referrals that have the newest date, or null for referrals if it doesnt have it

like this:

```
CarePlanId   ReferralId    ReferralDate
----------   ----------    ------------
1            1             05/15/12
2            NULL          NULL
```

Thanks - i hope this makes sense

Comment: having trouble readin what yo want but I think what you need is to look up how to do a cte or derived table.

Comment: Can you show sample data and desired results? Like @HLGEM it's not clear where you're starting and where you want to end up.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
select *
from CarePlan c
outer apply (
    select top 1 * --top N rows
    from Referral r
    where r.CarePlanId = c.CarePlanId --join condition
    order by /*fill this in!*/
) x
```

Be aware that this forces a loop join due to optimizer weaknesses up to and including version 2014.

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is older, but there is another approach which I feel is under-utilized:

You can join tables back to themselves and use an operator to find the "most recent" record.

**Answer**

```
SELECT CP.CarePlanId, R.ReferralId, R.ReferralDate
FROM CarePlan CP
LEFT OUTER JOIN Referral R ON R.CarePlanId = CP.CarePlanId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Referral R_NEWER ON R.CarePlanId = R_NEWER.CarePlanId AND R.ReferralDate < R_NEWER.ReferralDate
WHERE R_NEWER.ReferralId IS NULL
```

results:

```
CP.CarePlanId   R.ReferralId    R.ReferralDate
----------      ----------      ------------
1               1               05/15/12
2               NULL            NULL
```

**Explanation**

Let's break this down.  You are basically saying, for each referral record, (left outer) join to every other referral record that is associated with the same CarePlanId but ONLY where there is a newer ReferralDate.

Here is the query without the where clause (along with some addition info from the R_NEWER table):

```
SELECT CP.CarePlanId, R.ReferralId, R.ReferralDate, R_NEWER.ReferralId, R.NEWER.ReferralDate
FROM CarePlan CP
LEFT OUTER JOIN Referral R ON R.CarePlanId = CP.CarePlanId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Referral R_NEWER ON R.CarePlanId = R_NEWER.CarePlanId AND R.ReferralDate < R_NEWER.ReferralDate
```

Here is the result of that query:

```
CP.CarePlanId   R.ReferralId    R.ReferralDate  R_NEWER.ReferralId  R_NEWER.ReferralDate
----------      ----------      ------------    ------------        ------------    
1               1               05/15/12        NULL                NULL
2               NULL            NULL            NULL                NULL
1               2               05/10/12        1                   05/15/12
```

As you can see, only referral Id 2 (3rd record above) found a "newer" record to join to in the referral table (i.e. referral Id 1).  Referral Id 1 (1st record above) did NOT find a "newer" referral (for the same CarePlanId).

So, with this in mind, now we just add the where clause back:

```
SELECT CP.CarePlanId, R.ReferralId, R.ReferralDate, R_NEWER.ReferralId, R.NEWER.ReferralDate
FROM CarePlan CP
LEFT OUTER JOIN Referral R ON R.CarePlanId = CP.CarePlanId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Referral R_NEWER ON R.CarePlanId = R_NEWER.CarePlanId AND R.ReferralDate < R_NEWER.ReferralDate
WHERE R_NEWER.ReferralId IS NULL
```

and get:

```
CP.CarePlanId   R.ReferralId    R.ReferralDate  R_NEWER.ReferralId  R_NEWER.ReferralDate
----------      ----------      ------------    ------------        ------------    
1               1               05/15/12        NULL                NULL
2               NULL            NULL            NULL                NULL
```

At this point, just remove your R_NEWER columns from your SELECT as they are not needed any more and you have your answer.

It is important to remember that the "where" applies AFTER the joins have been occurred, but the ON statement occurs at the time of the join.  To make this more understandable for me, I always try to write the SELECTs and JOINs and return columns from each table I am joining and then add my WHERE clauses once I have a clear picture of what is returned.

**Caveat**
This approach works great in most cases, but it is possible to have duplicate rows if you had 2 referrals (for the same CarePlanId) with the date of 05/15/12 and that date was the "most recent."  To work around that, you could extend your join(s) to limit based on the "highest" ReferralId if that scenario arises.

Comment: Answered 5 year ago, but this answer is the best so far, works with JPA 2.1 too.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess. I'm not sure if EF is going to have issues with CTE syntax - can you force EF to call a stored procedure so you're not handcuffed by the subset of functionality supported by EF?

```
;WITH r AS 
(
  SELECT CarePlanId, MAX(ReferralDate)
    FROM dbo.Referrals GROUP BY CarePlanId
)
SELECT * FROM dbo.CarePlan AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN r 
  ON r.CarePlanId = c.CarePlanId;
```

Comment: sorry - i guess its more of a general SQL question, Entity Framework shouldnt matter here - at least i hope. I'm also hoping that the careplans returned are distinct (only one with the newest referral is used)

Comment: Only you can tell us the latter - have you trued to run the query? Does it return the results you expect? If you show us sample data and what you expect for output, it is much easier for us to try our answers before throwing them over the wall at you. It also saves everyone time.